# Prove absolute convergence given the following inequality

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

We are given the following inequality:

$|e^{x}-1|\leq|x|e^{|x|}$ where $x \in \mathbb C$

Prove that if $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} a_{n} $ converges absolutely in $\mathbb C$ then:

$\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} (e^{a_{n}}-1) $ converges absolutely.

**My thoughts:** Seeing as though we have to use the above inequality it eventually boils down to showing that $|a_{n}|e^{|a_{n}|}< c_{n} $ whereby $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} c_{n}$ converges absolutely.

I am assumung that since the series of $a_{n}$ converges absolutely then $|a_{n} | \to 0, n \to \infty$ thus implying that $|a_{n}|$ is bounded. I can't seem to find a bound that helps me along this path.

Am I on the right path, or should I take a whole new direction altogether.

Comment: $e^{|a_n|}$ is bounded, since $a_n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Yes, but that does not prove the series thereof converges.

Comment: Yes it does.
By assumption $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N} |a_n| \lt + \infty$. In particular, $a_n \to 0$, so $e^{|a_n|}$ converges and thus $e^{|a_n|}$ is bounded by a constant $K \gt 0$.
Therefore $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} |e^{a_{n}}-1| \leq \sum_{n\in\Bbb N}  |a_n|e^{|a_n|} \leq \sum_{n\in\Bbb N} K |a_n| = K \sum_{n\in\Bbb N} |a_n| \lt +\infty$.